# wxSizer and wxStaticBitmap ignore minimum size

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

```
Wizard::Wizard( wxWindow* parent, const wxString& archive )
: wxWizard(parent, wxID_ANY, _("Wizard"))
{    
    this->SetSizeHints( wxSize( -1,-1 ), wxDefaultSize );

    wxWizardPageSimple* rcModWizPageSelect = new wxWizardPageSimple( this );
    m_pages.Add( rcModWizPageSelect );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer1;
    bSizer1 = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

    m_bitmap2 = new wxStaticBitmap( rcModWizPageSelect, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap( wxT("data/img.jpg"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_bitmap2->SetMinSize( wxSize( 586,192 ) );

    bSizer1->Add( m_bitmap2, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxFIXED_MINSIZE, 5 );

    wxStaticBoxSizer* sbSizer1;
    sbSizer1 = new wxStaticBoxSizer( new wxStaticBox( rcModWizPageSelect, wxID_ANY, _("Select Archive") ), wxVERTICAL );

    rcModArchivePicker = new wxFilePickerCtrl( rcModWizPageSelect, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, _("Select a file"), wxT("*.zip"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxFLP_DEFAULT_STYLE|wxFLP_FILE_MUST_EXIST|wxFLP_OPEN );
    sbSizer1->Add( rcModArchivePicker, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 5 );

    bSizer1->Add( sbSizer1, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 5 );

    rcModWizPageSelect->SetSizer( bSizer1 );
    rcModWizPageSelect->Layout();
    bSizer1->Fit( rcModWizPageSelect );
    wxWizardPageSimple* rcModWizPageProgress = new wxWizardPageSimple( this );
    m_pages.Add( rcModWizPageProgress );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer2;
    bSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

    m_bitmap1 = new wxStaticBitmap( rcModWizPageProgress, wxID_ANY, wxBitmap( wxT("data/img.jpg"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_bitmap1->SetMinSize( wxSize( 586,192 ) );

    bSizer2->Add( m_bitmap1, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxFIXED_MINSIZE, 5 );

    wxStaticBoxSizer* sbSizer2;
    sbSizer2 = new wxStaticBoxSizer( new wxStaticBox( rcModWizPageProgress, wxID_ANY, _("Please Wait") ), wxVERTICAL );

    rcModInstallProgress = new wxGauge( rcModWizPageProgress, wxID_ANY, 100, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxGA_HORIZONTAL|wxGA_SMOOTH );
    rcModInstallProgress->SetValue( 0 ); 
    sbSizer2->Add( rcModInstallProgress, 0, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 5 );

    bSizer2->Add( sbSizer2, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND, 5 );

    rcModWizPageProgress->SetSizer( bSizer2 );
    rcModWizPageProgress->Layout();
    bSizer2->Fit( rcModWizPageProgress );

    this->Centre( wxBOTH );

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i < m_pages.GetCount(); i++ )
    {
        m_pages.Item( i )->SetPrev( m_pages.Item( i - 1 ) );
        m_pages.Item( i - 1 )->SetNext( m_pages.Item( i ) );
    }
}
```

I try to have a nice Wizard Dialog, but the minimum size gets ignored and the overall frame is much smaller than my image is. The image has a size of 586x192.

The preview looks nice in wxFormBuilder but the generated Code looks totally different.
Here 2 images:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbOzP.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3vVf.png

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and was able to work around it by calling SetItemMinSize() on the sizer as follows:

```
sizer->Add(control, 0, 0, 0);
sizer->SetItemMinSize(control, 150, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well want to check if your actual parent widget follows the size of it's children or recognizes them. I'd think that your widget itself (the picture) has the correct size but the Window/Frame around it doesn't have the correct size so it is showed "out of bounds".
Try to make the Window apply the size changes of it's children, look here for reference:
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_windowsizing.html

And:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a2bf38a6cbd1f82fb46f274396f482994   http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_sizer.html#abad9cedc0cbe9ade2c799da23462d17e

Hope that helps greets,

Roin

Comment: Hm well my idea was more to call Fit() on the actual frame or the actual window or maybe on both the window and your rcModWizPageSelect, but if that doesn't work either it seems to be a really strange issue. Even though your window might be calculating it's size depending on the actual screen resolution instead of looking at the widgets inside and applying a min size of it's own (did you set a min size for your window?)